# SVG circle take all the height preserving aspectratio on any div size

Tags: css, svg

The idea is to draw a circle in SVG that takes the whole height on the parent div whatever the size of the parent div. The width should be somehow ignored.

I've been working a bit with aspect ratio of SVG but this does not really work on all scenarios :

```
<div style='width:400px;height:100px'>  
<svg  width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
  <text x="100" y="50">Example SVG text 1</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

With the div width defined with 200px it's working.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91sp2j0x/11/

Comment: Just remove the width in your svg

Comment: You've an issue with the middle one, that should show the whole text (we've 500px width) -> https://jsfiddle.net/91sp2j0x/11/

Comment: svg {overflow:visible;} will fix it

Comment: anyway what I think is a wrong aproach is to put the text inside the svg. I would place it outside svg and inside div and position it later with css. Just my humble opinion. Do not mean any offense

Comment: Are there any constraints such as you need to have widths, and need to have overflow:hidden on the divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a value of `50` for the `r` attribute will allow the nested svg element to maintain a `100%` height of its containing (parent) element.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.resize-demonstration {
  resize: auto;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container-model {
  border-right: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<p>Resize the element below <u>vertically</u> or <u>horzontally</u> to demonstrate the intended behaviour</p>
<p><em>Note:</em> the <code>svg</code> has been wrapped in an containing element for <em>user-friendly resizing</em> (interaction with the resizing icon in the bottom-right corner), this is <strong>only for the sake of demonstration</strong> and should not be considered required.</p>
<div class="resize-demonstration" style="height: 100px">
  <div style='width:50px;height:100%;overflow:hidden;' class="container-model">
    <svg height="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
      <text x="100" y="50">100px width : Nothing is visible</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91sp2j0x/13/)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you would like to happen? I set the height of the div for each of the divs to different heights, and set the divs to `display: inline-block` so that the width is not 100%, as divs usually are by default, since they are block elements. That way the height of the SVG will be the height of the div.

```
<div style='height:200px;display:inine-block;overflow:hidden'>
<svg   height="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
  <text x="100" y="50">200px h</text>
</svg>
</div>
<div style='height:500px;display:inine-block;overflow:hidden'>
<svg height="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
  <text x="100" y="50">500px h</text>
</svg>
</div>
<div style='height:300px;display:inine-block;overflow:hidden'>
<svg height="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
  <text x="100" y="50">300px h</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suefeng/v14e7b81/2/

Comment: You should be able to add widths to each of the divs, though it cuts off the svg. They should still take on the height of the div though.

Comment: If you must have widths for all the divs, alternatively you can set the widths to width: auto in a stylesheet to override the width attributes, so that widths are ignored. You'd have to have a class name assigned to each of the divs though, such as .svg-container.

Answer (score 2):

with `preserveAspectRatio="none"` and `svg{width:100%}` will give 100% adjusted height.

```css
svg{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style='width:200px;height:100px;overflow:hidden'>
<svg   height="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
  <text x="100" y="50">200px w: cut text</text>
</svg>
</div>
<div style='width:500px;height:100px;overflow:hidden'>
<svg height="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
  <text x="100" y="50">500px w: full visible text</text>
</svg>
</div>
<div style='width:50px;height:100px;overflow:hidden'>
<svg height="100%" viewbox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
  <text x="100" y="50">100px width : Nothing is visible</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understood right, u want to have the circle with the radius of the height...
I did that successfully like so (if i understood what u asked correctly):

```
    <div style='width:800px;height:120px;'>  
<svg  viewbox="0 -10 200 140" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">  /* just remove the height and the width from the svg, it will take the parameters from the div... */ 
  <circle cx="18%" cy="18%" r="18%" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="red" />
  <text x="100" y="50">Example SVG text 1</text>
</svg>
</div>
```